# No Labels being displayed in MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Could someone let me know why my labels are not being displayed. I am running a loop thru an array with coordinates in it. Its displaying my 3 pins with 1 being green, two blue which is what i want but my labels are not being displayed, any ideas?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var maps: MKMapView!
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var flag = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let CoordinatesArray = ["blah,-blah, 11:45","blah, -blah,00:00", "blah,-blah, 12:45"];
        self.maps.delegate = self
        sendPoints(CoordinatesArray);

    }

    func sendPoints(array:[String]){
        let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.015 //difference of lats from one side of screen to another
        let longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.015 //difference of lats from one side of screen to another
        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)

        for (var i=0;i<array.count;i++){

            var separateComma = array[i].componentsSeparatedByString(",")
            var location:CLLocationCoordinate2D

            if(flag){
                location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(separateComma[0].doubleValue,separateComma[1].doubleValue)
                let length:CLLocationDistance = 200
                let cir:MKCircle = MKCircle(centerCoordinate: location, radius: length)
                maps.addOverlay(cir)


            }else{
                location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(separateComma[0].doubleValue,separateComma[1].doubleValue)

            }

            let point = MKPointAnnotation()
            point.title = "Home"
            point.subtitle = "time for home"
            point.coordinate = location
            maps.addAnnotation(point)
            maps.selectAnnotation(point, animated: true)
            maps.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMake(point.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta,longDelta)), animated: true)

        }
    }


    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let overlayRenderer : MKCircleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay);
        overlayRenderer.lineWidth = 150
        overlayRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        overlayRenderer.alpha = 0.15

        return overlayRenderer
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        if (annotation.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation)){
            return nil
        }
        var myPin = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("MyIdentifier") as? MKPinAnnotationView
        if myPin != nil {
            return myPin
        }

        myPin = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "MyIdentifier")
        if(flag){
            myPin?.pinTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        }else{
            myPin?.pinTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        }
        flag = false;
        return myPin
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

extension String {
    var doubleValue: Double {
        return (self as NSString).doubleValue
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no "labels" in your code, so what exactly are you asking about?

Comment: The point.title and point.subtitle should display the label?

Comment: No, they set the caption of the callout but they do not magically make it appear. The user has to tap the annotation.

Comment: Lol, yeah but when I touch nothing is displayed. It used to work but I changed my code and now nothing. Might be the simulator playing up, I'll try it on a device

Comment: "It used to work but I changed my code" Well, what did you change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `canShowCallout` property.

```
    myPin = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "MyIdentifier")
    myPin?.canShowCallout = true
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was delegating the map before being called.

So... that'd be the mistake I was facing.

```
self.m_map = MKMapView()
self.m_map?.delegate = self
```

Hope it helps somebody :-)